# When should I use the word artisanal versus craft?

Tags: difference

When is something **artisanal** versus **craft**?
Why do we say *artisanal chocolate* but *craft beer*?

I couldn't find anything distinguishing the two on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Artisanal is a 16th century loan word from French, and is used for a product, especially food or drink, made in a traditional or non-mechanized way. It possibly is more used in the UK and Europe, but is found in USA usage. Craft means the same thing, especially for beer, and possibly more common in the US. Both terms are usable for beer.

> Wholesaler Simply Hops has launched Beer is Here, a website linking hundreds of artisanal beer brands together in one place so that drinkers all over Europe can buy from their local supplier.

See [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk01ZAmjZnxAACpkXkoAcEZT_j1DKuw%3A1606989564268&ei=_LbIX6yCEMOT8gKV2r74Cg&q=%22artisanal%20beer%22&oq=%22artisanal%20beer%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjICCAAyAggAOgQIABBHOgUIABDJAzoICC4QxwEQrwE6BggAEBYQHlDdaFjjcmCSfWgAcAJ4AIABjAKIAfEDkgEDMi0ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwis8IrRxrHtAhXDiVwKHRWtD68Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)

> Word origin C16: from French, from Old Italian artigiano, from arte
> art

[Artisanal (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/artisan)

Comment: "Artisan" as a noun derievs from Italian (see https://www.etymonline.com/word/artisan)  dating from the 1530s. As an adjective (Artisan well) it comes through the French, in the early 1600s. "Artisanal " is I believe derived directly from the noun. In any case 400+ years is surely long enough for the word to be fully assimilated, and no longer thought of as a "loan word".

Comment: @DavidSiegel - 
I only started seeing the adjective in English in the last 10 years or so, whereas I had seen it in French for a while longer. Wells not needing pumps are artesian, from French artésien ‘from Artois’, where such wells were first made.

Comment: Actually, I think that artisanal been *over-used* in the US, particularly as a marketing gimmick.  At the end of 2013, an opinion columnist the *New York Times* identified "artisan" as one of the ["words for the dumpster"](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/12/29/opinion/egan-words-for-the-dumpster.html?_r=0).

Comment: @Canadian Yankee The term "artisanal " has certainly been much more common in theUSs in the past few years than it used to be, and has become a marketing tool. But the noun "artisan", meaning a skilled craftsman, is long established in English, and to derive an adjective from a noun by adding "-al" is standard and does nort need a fresh borrowing.

Comment: I agree with the NYT columnist. I do like craft beers and breads though.